# Pattern for specifying that a function's block is asynchronous vs synchronous

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a pattern for indicating that a function's blocks are called synchronously or asynchronously, for instance:

```
- (void)processImage:(UIImage *)image onComplete:(void (^)(NSError *__error))onComplete;
```

is a function that will synchronously process an image and then call `onComplete(error)` when done but:

```
- (void)downloadResourceIDs:(NSArray *)imageIDs onComplete:(void (^)(NSError *__error))onComplete;
```

is a function that will asynchronously download resources specified in an array and call `onComplete(error)` after everything is downloaded however it isn't immediately obvious that this is an asynchronous callback.  For instance I could use a `dispatch_semaphore` in `downloadResourceIDs:onComplete:` to prevent the callback from happening until everything is downloaded.

Alternatively should all functions be synchronous, even when the function itself incorporates asynchronous elements (like downloading things asynchronously) and artificially force synchronicity?

Comment: If an operation is performed synchronously, why use a block at all? Any code that would be in the block can just be written after the method call (and the method can return a `BOOL` and take an `NSError**` to signal errors)?

Comment: @一二三: That may be true in cases when the block is meant to be run at the end, e.g. in this case since it's called "onComplete". However, what if the block is meant to be run in the middle? For example, `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` is synchronous.

Comment: @newacct Ah, so perhaps the naming convention of the block is the indicator 'onComplete', 'onSuccess', 'onFailure' imply asynchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that a completion block is sufficient to communicate an asynchronous call.

For my money, the first interface is just horribly wrong.  A synchronous call does not need a completion block, and should not have on in the interface.

Comment: I think you may have a point here, digging around but I think this is the answer.

Comment: Yea, in that scenario I should do what 一二三 suggests which is return an object (if necessary) or BOOL (at least) and use an NSError**.